# Rails add elements to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method to calculated the average for a given set of records:

```
input = params[:recommendation_ratings].values  # The params are sent from radio_tags in my view.

input.each do |mini_params|
rating_id = mini_params[:rating_id]
l = Rating.find(rating_id) #Find record on Rating table. 
l.rating #Get value associated with rating_id
total_rating = []
total_rating << l.rating
average = total_rating.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / total_rating.size
puts average
end
```

l.rating is not being appended to the total_rating array. The puts average is being printed as:

```
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
```

How do I append each of the ratings being returned to the array to calculated the average,and other math functions.

Comment: based on your code, total_rating will always have 1 element only because you're setting it to an empty array.

Comment: What do I change so that each of the ratings are added to that empty array? Thanks!

Comment: can you update the code and paste the whole method from where this code came from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
total_rating = []    
input.each do |mini_params|
  rating_id = mini_params[:rating_id]
  l = Rating.find(rating_id) #Find record on Rating table. 
  total_rating << l.rating      
end
average = total_rating.sum / total_rating.size.to_f
```

Answer (score 2):

this should solve your issue but there is a better way

```
total_rating = []    
input.each do |mini_params|
  rating_id = mini_params[:rating_id]
  l = Rating.find(rating_id) #Find record on Rating table. 
  total_rating << l.rating
  average = total_rating.inject(:+).to_f / total_rating.size
  puts average
end
```

So given an array of ids, try the following

```
Rating.where(id: mini_params[:rating_id]).average(:rating)
```

UPDATE: fixing the one line version

```
rating_ids = input.map { |mini_params| mini_params[:rating_id] }
Rating.where(id: rating_ids).average(:rating)
```

Comment: This is giving me the same output as before.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `Rating.where("id in (?)", input.map{ |i| i[:rating_id] }).average(:rating)` ?

Comment: yup nurettin, you're right. i assumed that mini_params[:rating_id] is the array of ids.

Comment: @Yogzzz if this is giving the same output (3 for all averages), then that means the rating for the records you're finding is 3. can you check that out?

Comment: @jvnill, you're right. The update you provided works, however it is returning 3 results(because its in the block). Moving it out of the block returns what I need. Thanks!

Comment: no worries. i assumed you want to show the average everytime the array grows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get all of the ratings you are trying to average. I'm assuming you have already done this, and all of those ratings are stored in `total_rating`. Then you need to add the specific rating to that array:

```
rating_id = mini_params[:rating_id]
l = Rating.find(rating_id)
total_rating << l
average = total_rating.sum.to_f / total_rating.size
puts average
```